# The PDE of the probability hitting the barrier before T

Tags: black-scholes-pde, exotics, differential-equations, barrier

Suppose:
$$d S=\mu S dt+\sigma Sd W$$
$Q(t,S)$ is the probability that $S$ hit the barrier $B(S_t<B)$ before $T,$ then $Q$ satisfies following `PDE`
$$Q_t+\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2_{SS}Q+\mu S Q_S=0.$$
Could I prove that this way

`Proof:`
$$Q(t,S)=\mathbb{P}(\tau_B\leq T)$$
here $\tau_B$ is the `first passage time` at level $B$.

Then use the `reflection principle` for a Wiener process:

We have
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_B\leq T)=2\mathbb{P}(S_T>B)=2\int^{\infty}_Bp(t,S,T,y)d y$$
Here $p(t,S,T,y)$ is the `transition function` of $S_T$

From `Kolmogorov backward equation` we know
$$p_t+\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2p_{SS}+\mu S p_S=0.$$
then take the derivatives into the integral, we done.

I am not sure is the whole process correct? And is there any standard way to calculate the such PDE of probability, since the default probability also meet this pde

Answer (score 2):

May be I have overlooked something, but I believe that
\begin{align*}
Q(t, S) = \mathbb{P}\left(\tau_{B} \le T \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right).
\end{align*}
Then $\{Q(t, S), \, 0<t < T\}$ is a martingale, and the PDE follows immediately, by noting that
\begin{align*}
dQ &= Q_t dt + Q_S dS + \frac{1}{2}Q_{SS} d\langle S, S\rangle_t\\
&=\Big(\underbrace{Q_t + \mu S Q_S + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2Q_{SS} S^2}_{=0}\Big)dt + \sigma S Q_S dW_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: @noob2: Thanks for the enhancement.

Comment: Could you please bring more precision on the justification of $Q(t,S)$ being a martingale? Otherwise your answer is great. Thanks!

Comment: @JejeBelfort: By tower law, it is easy to see that $\{Q(t, S), \, 0<t<T\}$ is a martingale.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection principal ? Reflection principle.

It holds for the Brownian process, not the GBM. [Reflection principle is quite specific to symmetric random walks].

By chance, if $\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}=0$ and $\sigma>0$, then you have : 
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau^S_B<T)=\mathbb{P}(\tau^W_{\frac{1}{\sigma}\ln(B)}<T)$$ and you can apply reflection principle.

Comment: yeah, this is one of my confusion, reflection principal doesn't hold for any process? Another confusion is that, if the barrier is moving, say $B(t),$ does it only depend on the final value $B(T)$ i.e $\mathbb{P}(\tau_{B(t)}<T)=2\mathbb{P}(W(T)>B(T))?$

Comment: maybe, reflection principal holds for all `Levy process` with $X_0=0,$ I think

Comment: no it does not hold for all levy processes. A poisson process is a levy process. Reflection principle is quite specific to symmetric random walk.